# Why does FontAwesome recommend including via a .js script instead of a CDN link?

Tags: javascript, font-awesome, cdn

I was looking for a CDN to link to for FontAwesome.
Their [website](http://fontawesome.io/get-started/) instead provides a [.js link](https://use.fontawesome.com/ffb7811af7.js) (rather than using, for instance, this [Open Source CDN](https://opensource.keycdn.com/fontawesome/4.6.3/font-awesome.min.css) I found)

Does it check the link (or maybe try several) to the CDN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like from deobfuscating and quickly skimming through the JS file that it is a "1 and done" type of solution, meaning:

It loads the necessary CSS, sets the font type for the images, and also does some sort of reporting on who is using their stuff.

It also looks like it might bind their icons to the use of `fa` within a class

It doesn't really look like there is an obvious advantage to using the .js file over the CDN.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the free version of font-awesome, use [cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/font-awesome).

For pro users, [Setup Webfont with CDN](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/customizing-wordpress/snippets/setup-cdn-webfont) will provide insights on how to setup CDN with *pro.fontawesome.com*

---

#### Old Answer:

<strike>`use.fontawesome.com` is Font Awesome's own CDN.</strike>##

Heading

FontAwesome has its own paid option and analytics on usage provided by the CDN among many other features. Thats why they prefer thier own CDN for the end users.

Answer (score 2):

If you inspect the script file you get from the embed code, it starts off with the following:

```
window.FontAwesomeCdnConfig = {
    autoA11y: {
        enabled: true
    },
    asyncLoading: {
        enabled: true,
    },
    reporting: {
        enabled: true,
        domains: "localhost, *.dev"
    },
    useUrl: "use.fontawesome.com",
    faCdnUrl: "https://cdn.fontawesome.com:443",
    code: "5083f6dc23"
};
```

After which it simply loads the files from the CDN. This obviously means that there's (even if minuscule) extra overhead. So what's really going on here?

There's two good candidates for why FA is picking this approach:

1. Harvesting e-mails: they have some paid products and wouldn't it be just great if they could e-mail people who are already interested in similar products about them?
2. Statistics: each generated script has a seemingly unique code which can be used to keep track of who uses how much of their bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that using the .js file allows additional features such as asynchronous loading and automatic accessibility. It would not surprise me if they also do more tracking. Asynchronous loading means that the apparent overhead is actually *less*.

Answer (score 0):

I cam here because I was appalled at the number of scripts fontawesome loaded into my web page (as well as insisting to be placed above the fold).

I have since used this;
http://opensource.keycdn.com/fontawesome/4.6.3/font-awesome.min.css
which, of course, will need keeping up to date and,  whereas one can appreciate the need for fontawesome to produce some revenue stream, I would have preferred them to be more up from about the number of calls involved.

There is an option to use the fontawesome CDN as a CSS file, perhaps that addresses some of the issues.